# 404 error when query string contains com1 for WebApi hosted on IIS 10

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, iis-10

I have a simple WebApi solution hosted on IIS10.

I have a ProductController class that inherits ApiController. This class has a method GetProduct

```
 [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/product/{productName}")]
    public object GetProduct(string productName)
    {
        return "abc";
    }
```

When I try to hit the following api through postman

http://localhost:10000/api/product/com1?query=test

I get a 404 error, Tried to create a folder by the same name (com1) but got an error as well. Then found out that I cannot have the following values in my api
CON, PRN, AUX, NUL, COM1, COM2, COM3, COM4, COM5, COM6, COM7, COM8, COM9, LPT1, LPT2, LPT3, LPT4, LPT5, LPT6, LPT7, LPT8, and LPT9.

I tried adding the following entries in IIS
under Request Filtering

[image]

Am I missing out on anything?

Comment: Check this [blog post](https://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/29/allowing-reserved-filenames-in-URLs.aspx/)

Comment: Perfect thank you, would love to mark this comment as an answer

Comment: you found out you can't have those values in your URLs and you are asking how to use them -- you should be asking how not to have them.  They are a security risk.  Just don't use those values.

Answer (score 1):

the blog suggested by [Željko Huber](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11119579/%C5%BDeljko-huber) worked for me. [blog post](https://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/29/allowing-reserved-filenames-in-URLs.aspx/)

Answer (score 0):

make sure productNamed and productName matches, I ran into an error recently as well because the names didn't match.. crazy haha i was using Swagger and it gave me two fields to fill out when i only needed one..

```
 [HttpGet]
 [Route("api/product/{productName}")]
 public object GetProduct(string productName)
 {
     return "abc";
 }
```

Comment: Made the change but still got an error. I replace the value with anything besides these CON, PRN, AUX, NUL, COM1, COM2, COM3, COM4, COM5, COM6, COM7, COM8, COM9, LPT1, LPT2, LPT3, LPT4, LPT5, LPT6, LPT7, LPT8, and LPT9.
 and it works

Answer (score 0):

Your route name does not match the parameter name. Make both of them "productNamed" or "productName".

Comment: tried but same results. Anything besides the following CON, PRN, AUX, NUL, COM1, COM2, COM3, COM4, COM5, COM6, COM7, COM8, COM9, LPT1, LPT2, LPT3, LPT4, LPT5, LPT6, LPT7, LPT8, and LPT9.